# PHP : Conditional based on the items hierarchy in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array, I want to make conditional action based on the items hierarchy in the array. I'm going to compare between items based on their hierarchy and it will result a 2 dimensional array like this.

[image]

The comparison is : Imagine that there are 3 stair, in the highest stair is 5, the second stair is 3 and the last stair is 1.

[image]

If a number compared with the 1st lower floor then it'll be 3 and if a number compared with the 2nd lower floor then it'll be 5. Example : if 5 is compared with 3 then it'll be 3, if 5 is compared with 1 then it'll be 5. If a number compared with the 1st upper floor then it'll be 1/3 and if a number compared with the 2nd upper floor then it'll be 1/5. Example if 1 is compared with 3 then it'll be 1/3 and if 1 is compared with 5 then it'll be 1/5. And if 3 is compared with 5 then it'll be 1/3 and if 3 is compared with 1 then it'll be 3.

So far, this is my code

```
$weightvalue = array(5,3,1);
$numbers = count($weightvalue);
for ($row = 0; $row < $numbers; $row++) {
    for ($column = 0; $column < $numbers; $column++) {
        echo "$weightvalue[$row],$weightvalue[$column] ";
        if ($weightvalue[$row]==$weightvalue[$column]) {echo "1";}
        elseif ($weightvalue[$row]<$weightvalue[$column]) {echo "1/3";}
        elseif ($weightvalue[$row]<$weightvalue[$column]) {echo "1/5";}
        elseif ($weightvalue[$row]>$weightvalue[$column]) {echo "3";}
        elseif ($weightvalue[$row]>$weightvalue[$column]) {echo "5";}
        else {echo "false";};
        echo ("\n");
    }
}
```

So far this is the result, but there're some mistakes, I know what causes this but I don't know how to fix it. Please help, any suggestion will very much appreciated.

[image]